# How to stay in the same FSM state after input turns zero? (SystemVerilog)

Tags: system-verilog, led, fsm

I am trying to make an FSM that turns on different LEDS on an LED matrix depending on the button pressed. However, the LED doesn't stays on and after releasing the button, the first LED turns on again.
Here is the code:

```
module OneLed( input logic clk, reset, input logic [1:0] button, 
           output logic [7:0] rows, 
           output logic shcp, stcp, mr, oe, ds); //The LED matrix has 3 74hc595 shift registers below it

      logic [7:0] [23:0] in;
      logic [1:0] butreg; // thought a register would remember the button input
      assign butreg = button; 

      //FSM
      typedef enum logic [1:0] {S0, S1, S2} statetype;
      statetype state , nextstate;

     //state register
     always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge reset)
           if (reset) state <= S0;
           else state <= nextstate;

     //next state logic 
           always_comb
                 case(butreg)
                     S0: if (2'b01) nextstate = S1;
                         else if (2'b10) nextstate = S2;
                         else nextstate = S0;

                     S1: if (2'b01) nextstate = S2;
                         else if (2'b10) nextstate = S0;
                         else nextstate = S1;

                     S2: if (2'b01) nextstate = S0;
                         else if (2'b10) nextstate = S1;
                         else nextstate = S2;     
                     default: nextstate = S0;
           endcase 

    //output logic 
    always_comb
           begin
               if (state == S0)
                  in [0] = 24'b10000000_00000000_00000000;
               else if (state == S1)
                  in [0] = 24'b00000000_10000000_00000000;
               else  if (state == S2)        
                  in[0] =  24'b00000000_00000000_10000000;
   end         

   led LED ( clk, in , rows, shcp, stcp, mr, oe, ds); // this module works fine
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assign butreg = button;
```

This statement treats **butreg** as a wire, that is connected directly to your input signal **button**.

If you are looking to latch the value of **button** into the register **butreg**, you would need to use a **always** block and trigger at the appropriate event (posedge clk or * or some other condition.

For example, instead of the above assign, you may have

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (button == 2'b00) begin
    butreg <= butreg;
  end
  else begin
    butreg <= button;
  end
end
```